# Does Pentaho Spoon support -param?

Tags: command-line, parameter-passing, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

New to Pentaho, enjoying the spoon gui, but it seems not be possible to import parameters with command line arguments like

```
-param:abc=def
```

I only got this to work with Kitchen, but this does not have the gui.

Perhaps because spoon might open multiple jobs and transformations, while kitchen opens just one job, from the command line.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not as you imagine it.

Just open the Job/Transformation in Spoon and click on the "Run" button. You'll be presented with the "Run Options" dialog which lists all parameters defined in the job/transformation. Edit the Value column and that's it.

But spoon won't be able to run multiple instances of the same job in parallel, it will only run one. To launch multiple copies in parallel you'll need a parent job that calls the same sub-job multiple times with different parameter values, and is set to launch all those copies in parallel.

Comment: Very useful answer, but the command line parameters do not show in that dialog, neither als Parameters, nor as Variables, nor under "Arguments(Legacy)". Should I assume that the command line parameters are simply ignored by Pentaho Spoon?

Comment: the -param option in the command line only does one thing: pass a value to be used as a parameter value. In Spoon those parameters are set at runtime, not when launching spoon from the command line.

Comment: I accept this answer, asssuming that the answer means `spoon does not support setting a parameter with the -param command line argument, unlike kitchen`